# how to connect iphone device to non iphone device?

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, xcode4.3, ios5.1

I am new to this iPhone development.Currently I am working on an application which requires data transfer from iPhone to non iPhone device like android.Can any one suggest me a method to do this?IS there any libraries or API or framework to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try Bump API's Link http://bu.mp/api

Comment: user1369364 is looking for a programming solution.. not a ready made app to just transfer data

Comment: Or you can also use i cloud o storybord api's

Answer (score -2):

You should go through these two questions -

[iPhone - how is data transferred in P2P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084799/iphone-how-is-data-transferred-in-p2p)

[Is it possible, in principle, for an Android device to interface with an iPhone over Bluetooth/GameKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080644/is-it-possible-in-principle-for-an-android-device-to-interface-with-an-iphone)

Hope that helps

Comment: I really hate people who downvote but don't mention the reason in the comments!!

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you linked without explanation, which isn't encouraged. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259